# How to check for a subset of allowed types in flow (JS)?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Let's say I have two types, one a subcategory of the other:

```
type Set = 'A' | 'B' | 'C';
type SubSet = 'A' | 'B';
```

And two functions, one of which is called from within the other:

```
const outer = (argument: Set) => { 
    if (['A', 'B'].contains(argument) {
        inner(argument);
    };

const info = { 'A': something, 'B': something };
const inner = (argument: SubSet) => { info[argument] };
```

Flow will now show an `incompatible-call` error, since it thinks 'C' could be an input to inner, which is not allowed. In reality, this is caught by the if-statement, but flow does not recognise that.

It would be possible to change the inner argument type to `Set`, but that would cause flow to throw an `prop-missing` error. Is there any way to formulate this without using a third-party library for type checking like [flow-runtime](https://codemix.github.io/flow-runtime) or [runtime-types project](https://github.com/seanhess/runtime-types)?

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing `type Set = Subset | 'C'` to avoid code repitition?

Comment: shouldn't you do : `type Set = Subset | 'C' ` in the first place to avoid repeating code?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the ability for flow to refine your type of `A, B, C` to just `A, B`. This is known as type refinement.

Now your code is technically correct but checking if an anonymous array does or doesn't contain a particular value doesn't necessarily give flow the ability to refine your code flow to a point where it can determine if your function call is valid. You could consider this a minor downfall of flow, but it forces you to write code in a more standard way so that flow can understand how your code flows and it can analyze for you.

Here's the change I've made to your [code](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAyhxQLxQOQEEVQD6oEKZxQGEUBuAKFElgFcAjOBZdAvM88gYwHsA7AZwTcawCACckUABQBDMQHMaAWwi9gALljwAlEgB8UAN5RyUM1AD0FqAEsAZtIDaLADRsAugDobvTgBsaABMIflkFZVVgbV1DU3N7aTlFFTUkRGYMbBwkiNT05nwYuPN43l5xMOTI7QoSgF8KOo4eAQQfO25JYxZNFFFBFDcUfF7+4EwGrj5BWzLxSUrcjVoGHX0jWY7HHJTgdygGoA)

```
type Set = 'A' | 'B' | 'C';
type SubSet = 'A' | 'B';

const outer = (argument: Set) => { 
    if (argument === 'A' || argument === 'B') {
        inner(argument);
    };
}

const info = { 'A': 'test', 'B': 'test' };
const inner = (argument: SubSet) => { info[argument] };
```